# OneToOne JPA relation with composite primary key

Tags: java, jpa

I have this bidirectional OneToOne example that is not working:

```
@Embeddable
public class SolicitudGUCDetalleId implements Serializable {

  @Column(name = "IDPEDIDO", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  @Size(max = 36)
  private String idPedido;

  @Column(name = "IDLINEA", precision = 10, scale = 0, insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private long idLinea;

  ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TRIISOLIDGUCDET")
public class SolicitudGUCDetalle implements Serializable {

  @EmbeddedId
  private SolicitudGUCDetalleId id;

  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "solicitudGUCDetalle")
  private SolicitudGUCEnvio solicitudGUCEnvio;

  ...
}

@Embeddable
public class SolicitudGUCEnvioId implements Serializable {

  @Column(name = "IDPEDIDO", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  @Size(max = 36)
  private String idPedido;

  @Column(name = "IDLINEA", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private long idLinea;

  ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TRIISOLIDGUCENV")
public class SolicitudGUCEnvio implements Serializable {


  @EmbeddedId
  private SolicitudGUCEnvioId id;

  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @PrimaryKeyJoinColumns({
      @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "IDLINEA", referencedColumnName = "IDLINEA"),
      @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "IDPEDIDO", referencedColumnName = "IDPEDIDO")})
  private SolicitudGUCDetalle solicitudGUCDetalle;

  ...
}
```

I have read about the problem and I have two possible ways to implement this relation that are working.

1 - Use the same class for the composite primary key:

```
@Embeddable
public class SolicitudGUCId implements Serializable {

  @Column(name = "IDPEDIDO", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  @Size(max = 36)
  private String idPedido;

  @Column(name = "IDLINEA", precision = 10, scale = 0, insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private long idLinea;

  ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TRIISOLIDGUCDET")
public class SolicitudGUCDetalle implements Serializable {

  @EmbeddedId
  private SolicitudGUCId id;

  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "solicitudGUCDetalle")
  private SolicitudGUCEnvio solicitudGUCEnvio;

  ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TRIISOLIDGUCENV")
public class SolicitudGUCEnvio implements Serializable {

  @EmbeddedId
  private SolicitudGUCId id;

  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @PrimaryKeyJoinColumns({
      @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "IDLINEA", referencedColumnName = "IDLINEA"),
      @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "IDPEDIDO", referencedColumnName = "IDPEDIDO")})
  private SolicitudGUCDetalle solicitudGUCDetalle;

  ...
}
```

2 - Switch to a @OneToMany Relation and store the related entity in a Set:

```
@Embeddable
public class SolicitudGUCDetalleId implements Serializable {

  @Column(name = "IDPEDIDO", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  @Size(max = 36)
  private String idPedido;

  @Column(name = "IDLINEA", precision = 10, scale = 0, insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private long idLinea;

  ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TRIISOLIDGUCDET")
public class SolicitudGUCDetalle implements Serializable {

  @EmbeddedId
  private SolicitudGUCDetalleId id;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "solicitudGUCDetalle")
  private Set<SolicitudGUCEnvio> solicitudes;

  ...
}

@Embeddable
public class SolicitudGUCEnvioId implements Serializable {

  @Column(name = "IDPEDIDO", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  @Size(max = 36)
  private String idPedido;

  @Column(name = "IDLINEA", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private long idLinea;

  ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TRIISOLIDGUCENV")
public class SolicitudGUCEnvio implements Serializable {

  @EmbeddedId
  private SolicitudGUCEnvioId id;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumns({
      @JoinColumn(name = "IDLINEA", referencedColumnName = "IDLINEA",
          nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false),
      @JoinColumn(name = "IDPEDIDO", referencedColumnName = "IDPEDIDO",
          nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)})
  private SolicitudGUCDetalle solicitudGUCDetalle;

  ...
}
```

I would like to know if I can implement this relation following my first example. If the answer is no, I would like to know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I was looking for:

```
@Embeddable
public class SolicitudGUCDetalleId implements Serializable {

  @Column(name = "IDPEDIDO", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  @Size(max = 36)
  private String idPedido;

  @Column(name = "IDLINEA", precision = 10, scale = 0, insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private long idLinea;

  ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TRIISOLIDGUCDET")
public class SolicitudGUCDetalle implements Serializable {

  @EmbeddedId
  private SolicitudGUCDetalleId id;

  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "solicitudGUCDetalle")
  private SolicitudGUCEnvio solicitudGUCEnvio;

  ...
}

@Embeddable
public class SolicitudGUCEnvioId implements Serializable {

  @Column(name = "IDPEDIDO", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  @Size(max = 36)
  private String idPedido;

  @Column(name = "IDLINEA", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private long idLinea;

  ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TRIISOLIDGUCENV")
public class SolicitudGUCEnvio implements Serializable {


  @EmbeddedId
  private SolicitudGUCEnvioId id;

  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name = "IDLINEA", referencedColumnName = "IDLINEA"),
      @JoinColumn(name = "IDPEDIDO", referencedColumnName = "IDPEDIDO")})
  @MapsId
  private SolicitudGUCDetalle solicitudGUCDetalle;

  ...
}
```

@Brian Vosburgh , Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

This appears to a "derived identity"; so you might try a slight variation of your option 1:

```java
@Embeddable
public class SolicitudGUCId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "IDPEDIDO", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @Size(max = 36)
    private String idPedido;

    @Column(name = "IDLINEA", precision = 10, scale = 0, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private long idLinea;

    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TRIISOLIDGUCDET")
public class SolicitudGUCDetalle implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private SolicitudGUCId id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "solicitudGUCDetalle")
    private SolicitudGUCEnvio solicitudGUCEnvio;

    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TRIISOLIDGUCENV")
public class SolicitudGUCEnvio implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private SolicitudGUCId id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "IDLINEA", referencedColumnName = "IDLINEA"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "IDPEDIDO", referencedColumnName = "IDPEDIDO")})
    @MapsId
    private SolicitudGUCDetalle solicitudGUCDetalle;

    ...
}
```

Note that `SolicitudGUCEnvio.solicitudGUCDetalle` is annotated with `@MapsId` and `@JoinColumns` (as opposed to `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumns`).

Derived identities are discussed (with examples) in the [JPA 2.2 spec](https://github.com/javaee/jpa-spec/blob/master/jsr338-MR/JavaPersistence.pdf) in section 2.4.1.

Comment: Sorry, but in my comment I say that this example is working.

I'm trying to correct the first example, this has two diferents EmbeddedId. Thanks.

Comment: @jvano Ahh, my bad. You can use your first example, probably without any problems. But the JPA spec recommends you tweak it to be like the code in my response: "Note that the use of PrimaryKeyJoinColumn instead of MapsId would result in the same mapping in this example. Use of MapsId is preferred for the mapping of derived identities." [p. 38]